# Out-of-range Datetime issue using LINQtoSQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2000

Here is a snippet of my  model:

```
* SQL Server *

Event
-----
Id (int, PK) NOT NULL
Title (varchar(100)) NULL
LastModified (datetime) NULL

EventDates
----------
Id (int, PK) NOT NULL
StartDate (datetime) NULL
EndDate (datetime) NULL

* C# *

Event
-----
public int Id
public string Title
public DateTime LastModified

EventDates
----------
public int Id
public DateTime StartDate
public Datetime EndDate
```

The `LastModified` field has been in the database since its creation.  I have been saving it's value when I save an event, but I want to display it in a table, so I changed up my Event repository's `GetEvents`'s return value:

```
return (from e in GetDbEvents()
                select new Event
                {
                    // Miscellaneous fields..
                    LastModified = e.LastModified.GetValueOrDefault() // Shiny new code
                });
```

When I call this now, I get yelled at:

```
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type 
resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

If I strip down the above code to this, it still doesn't help and I get the same error if I attempt to enumerate over the result:

```
var test = (from e in _db.Events
                    select e.LastModified.GetValueOrDefault());
```

As a test, I did the same statement for my `EventDates` table (again, with 2 datetime columns):

```
 var test4 = (from ed in _db.EventDates
                     select new EventDate
                     {
                         StartDate = ed.StartDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
                         EndDate = ed.EndDate.GetValueOrDefault()
                     });
```

This works fine, of course.  No errors when I enumerate, all values are correct.

I should point out that some `LastModified` values in the `Events` table are `NULL` while all values in `EventDates` are populated with data.

### Edit

My  main question is why does `Events` give me out-of-range issues and `EventDates` does not, even though the model is quite similar?

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum (i.e. MIN() and MAX()) values of the dates in each of the table columns you're examining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the GetValueOrDefault(). This will return `DateTime.MinValue` (01-01-0001) in the "default" case and sqlserver doesn't accept that (it refuses dates before about 1753).

If you use a `Nullable<DateTime>`, then sql will be happy with the `null` it will get.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the declaration of your C# variable LastModified to `public DateTime? LastModified` that should fix your problem. The addition of the question mark indicates that it is a nullable type.

Comment: I will give that a shot.  My main question is, however - how come Events is having this problem and not EventDates? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/432248/linq-to-sql-datetime-getvalueordefault) is related?

One possible fix *(if you don't want to change LastModified to `DateTime?`, requiring you to litter your code with `.Value` everywhere..)* would be to get the values from the Database as `DateTime?`'s, but translate them to `DateTime`'s in your code.  For example:

```
return from e in GetDbEvents()
       select new Event(e.LastModified);

...

//In Event class:
public Event(DateTime? lastModified)
{
    LastModified = lastModified.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

This will cause `GetValueOrDefault()` to be called client-side, rather than being part of the SQL.

Note that this approach does have [problems of its own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic13)...

Comment: thanks for the links!  I like how the bug is a 'won't fix' - it just gives me more ammo for my "upgrade to 2008" fight :P

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Hans Keﬆing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781924/), and help people who encounter this issue in a filtering/WHERE clause rather than in the SELECT clause:

The problem is with the `GetValueOrDefault()` call. LINQ to SQL (somewhat stupidly IMO) translates this to real SQL by using a `COALESCE` clause (similar to `ISNULL`) like this:

```
COALESCE(LastModified, '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM')
```

Unfortunately, the SQL Server `datetime` data type doesn't accept dates before about 1753. So SQL Server throws the error back to LINQ to SQL, which throws it back to you.

If you use a Nullable, then SQL Server will be happy with the null it will get. But if you still want to use `GetValueOrDefault()`, e.g. in a query to filter the results you have a couple options:

1. `LastModified.GetValueOrDefault(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)`
2. `LastModified.HasValue && LastModified > DateTime.Now`